# CPU cores listed by "lscpu" doesn't match the model's no.of cores

Tags: linux, cpu

I was trying to find the no. of cpu cores our new server has when compared with the old one and it seems lscpu can display that information. So I ran it on one of the new servers, I get below output

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 37
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2698 v4 @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               2199.998
BogoMIPS:              4399.99
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              25600K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

Here, from the model name, it seems the server is having CPU E5-2698 v4 which according to [specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/91753/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2698-v4-50M-Cache-2_20-GHz) should have 20 cores but from the above info, it has 1 socket with 8 cores which doesn't map to 20 cores. how is this possible? Am I not interpreting it correctly? how can I know the right value of no. of cpu cores my server has? Also, the spec says it has 50 MB cache but it seems to be 25.6MB cache as seen in L3 cache. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `cat /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: Why is there `Hypervisor vendor:     VMware`? Maybe you don't have access to the 'bare metal'?

Comment: Yes, I tried cat /proc/cpuinfo and it still shows the same core, with siblings 8 and physical id 0.

Comment: Its a VM on ESXi host and hence it might showing VMWare. Can we configure VM with no. of cores that it can use?